# Ansible lineInFile insertbefore multiple times

Tags: regex, ansible

I have tried and searched around to solve this without anything suiting my issue.

Im using ansible to retrieve a config and i want to manipulate this config in a certain way. One thing i want to do is to add a tag before a line with a regex match, but on all of them.

```
hello
something
something
hello
something
hello
```

should be:

```
tag:
hello
something
something
tag:
hello
something
tag:
hello
```

i have tried using the module lineinfile with the insertbefore option, but this one only adds the tag once to the last match. I also tried with_items loop but my options dont change, i just want to have it done on all matches of the same regex with the same string getting added before.

Any ideas how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use replace module:

```
  - name: replace txt
    hosts: localhost
    tasks:
      - name: Replace before 
        ansible.builtin.replace:
          path: "./file.txt"
          regexp: '^(hello)$'
          replace: 'tag:\n\1'
```

**result:**

```
tag:
hello
something
something
tag:
hello
something
tag:
hello
```

if you use this regex:

```
      regexp: '^(?:tag:\n)?(hello)$'
      replace: 'tag:\n\1'
```

that doesnt add new `tag:`  if you replay the task

if you have problem with group:

```
          regexp: '^hello$'
          replace: 'tag:\nhello'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately this throws an error "re.error: invalid group reference 1 at position 7" so i think it has a problem with the ":".
Replayability isnt a problem, im pulling the config in the beginning of my playboob, but good to know thanks

Comment: ok no when i delete the colon it still throws this error

Comment: i have no error so....show what you have written...

Comment: Mhm it seems to have a problem with the \1

Comment: yes i have replace: 'tag:\n\1' ,when i remove the \1 it works

Comment: have you an old version of ansible?   anyways you could avoid the group see my answer modified

Comment: no im using newest version (ansible-core 2.12). Your addition does unfortunately not help because the line containing the "hello" is always a bit different

Comment: i have same version asible, but the problem is with version of python?

Comment: 3.9 so also newest

Comment: dont understand...https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html    in sample, we could see \1  as group....

Comment: I have found what i did wrong (thanks for barring with me because i dont know how these backreferences work). I didnt put my regex into a group.